# Ruby undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting the following error:
[image]

From the following code:

```
def information_transfer()
  file_contents = CSV.read("test.csv", col_sep: ",", encoding: "ISO8859-1")
  file_contents2 = CSV.read("applicantinfo.csv", col_sep: ",", encoding:"ISO8859-1")
  arraysize = file_contents.length
  arraysize1 = file_contents2.length
  for i in 1..arraysize
    for x in 1..arraysize1
      if file_contents[i][0] == file_contents2[x][0]
        CSV.open("language_output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
          csv << [file_contents[i][0], file_contents[i][1], file_contents[i][2],file_contents[i][3], file_contents[i][4], 
          file_contents[i][5], file_contents[i][6], file_contents[i][7], file_contents[i][8],file_contents[i][9], 
          file_contents[i][10], file_contents[i][11], file_contents[i][12], file_contents[i][13], file_contents[i][14],
          file_contents[i][15], file_contents[i][16], file_contents[i][17], file_contents[i][18], file_contents2[i][24],file_contents2[i][25], 
          file_contents2[i][26],file_contents2[i][27], file_contents2[i][28], file_contents2[i][29], file_contents2[i][30], file_contents2[i][31], file_contents2[i][32], file_contents2[i][33]]
        end
     end
   end
 end
end
```

I'm basically trying to take two individual .csv files and merge certain columns together.  I have two arrays (file_contents and file_contents2) that are reading the individual csv files and storing the contents in arrays.  For some reason i'm getting a syntax error for my if statement. I was hoping someone could help me figure out why the if statement that I wrote isn't valid.  I figured it would be.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you please point the line numbers which one is line:27

Comment: Its breaking in one of your `file_contents[i][5]` seems like `file_contents[i]` is nil somewhere

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for all the help! You guys all helped me figure it out! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like one of `file_contents` or `file_contents2` is empty.

You can skip the loop if you don't want to raise the error on that specific line.

```
next if file_contents[i].blank? || file_contents2[i].blank?
if file_contents[i][0] == file_contents2[x][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

One of your arrays `file_contents` or `file_contents2` might be empty. Output both, as well as printing `file_contents[i][0]` and `file_contents2[x][0]` before your `if` statement.

You can make a simple change that should work:

`for i in 0..arraysize
    for x in 0..arraysize1`

And add an error check:

`if !file_contents[i].blank? and !file_contents2[x].blank? and file_contents[i][0] == file_contents2[x][0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in 1..arraysize
  for x in 1..arraysize1
```

Array indexes run from 0 to length − 1 in Ruby; loop in `0...arraysize` instead.

*If* `file_contents2[i]` can or should be written as `file_contents2[x]`, you can just loop over the arrays’ contents directly:

```
for a in file_contents
  for b in file_contents2
```

and use slices to get consecutive array elements into another array:

```
def information_transfer()
  file_contents = CSV.read("test.csv", col_sep: ",", encoding: "ISO8859-1")
  file_contents2 = CSV.read("applicantinfo.csv", col_sep: ",", encoding: "ISO8859-1")
  for a in file_contents
    for b in file_contents2
      if a[0] == b[0]
        CSV.open("language_output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
          csv << a[0..18] + b[24..33]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and if you’re trying to join the two files one-to-one, you can do that more efficiently by putting the key into a hash. You also probably didn’t mean to reopen the output file every time.

```
def information_transfer()
  file_contents = CSV.read("test.csv", col_sep: ",", encoding: "ISO8859-1")
  file_contents2 = CSV.read("applicantinfo.csv", col_sep: ",", encoding: "ISO8859-1")

  h = Hash[file_contents.collect { |row| [row[0], row] }]

  CSV.open("language_output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    for b in file_contents2
      a = h[b[0]]
      csv << a[0..18] + b[24..33]
    end
  end
end
```